# Dynamic Classes forgotten on Firefox page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I've written some jQuery that fixes a sub menu in place once the user scrolls beyond it on the page. The jQuery alters the class on the submenu to make it fixed. This all works fine, apart from one scenario and that's if I refresh the page in Firefox - I don't experience this issue in any other browser.

```
$(function(){
    var menu = $('#submenu_wrapper'),
        pos = menu.offset();
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(this).scrollTop() >= pos.top-57 && menu.hasClass('')){
                menu.addClass('fixed');
                $('.content_push').css({"height":"109px"});
            } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= pos.top-57 && menu.hasClass('fixed')){
                menu.removeClass('fixed');
                $('.content_push').css({"height":"57px"});
            }
        });
});
```

Is there some alteration I can make so that Firefox will retain the altered class states if the page is refeshed? I've seen similar fixed menu behavour manage to do this, but can't seem to figure out how. [The Twitter Bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html) for example, if you go to the Javascript section does this exact thing.

Cheers.

Comment: I find it hard to believe you only see this "problem" in Firefox.

Comment: I've tried testing in Chrome, IE 9 and Safari - hitting F5 returns to the exact same point, all classes intact.

Comment: It may be that these other browsers are firing the scroll event on refresh and Firefox is not.  If this is the case, you can have code that checks to see if the scroll position is at the top of the page. If it is not at the top, run $(window).trigger('scroll');

Answer (score 1):

No, after a reload any modifications done by scripts are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I think ThiefMaster is correct. It surprises me that other browsers behave differently.

As a workaround, add a URL fragment (using #) when you show the submenu, and on page load, check for that fragment, and if it is present, run the script that shows the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to store a value in a cookie and, based on the value of this cookie on refresh, apply the proper class to the elements.